# Large List in SharePoint Online for Custom Reports?

Tags: sharepoint-online, reports, large-lists

I can't seem to find an explicit msdn article that mentions SharePoint Online can store up to 30,000,000 list items in a List. I saw that there is an article for the List View Threshold but it does not mention limits for the List itself. I assume it's similar to SharePoint 2013 which is 30,000,000 items.

We plan to use the list as a repository for "Custom Report"; an example would be when a search is performed, we 'track' the search and add an item to the list with data such as WHO performed the search, his / her username, etc.

One thing I am also concerned with this is querying the data, say, I only want items from August 2015. I can see that it is a fast growing list.

Is there a better way of doing what we want to do?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

30 million is the upper bound in SharePoint Online as well.

Search queries are automatically tracked. You can view them by going into the search settings of your SharePoint Online central administration and clicking the View Usage Reports. Is it vital to know who is looking for what? I would say no, proper security is going to block that anyway.

However, if you do need to go down that path, I would make sure it is architected properly, all applicable fields are indexed, any views necessary are precreated and do not exceed 5k items being returned, otherwise you are going to not be able to manage the list.

Comment: Thanks Eric! It would be useful for us to know for example, which users from departments are searching for what and analyze from there. Can you explain more what you mean with 'proper security'? Is a javascript CSOM call to add to a List not possible?

Yes, we are having careful consideration how to do it... If we try to query the List to read some data (ex. just for month of August), I think that should be okay. We can just save those in Excel and aggregate from there. Think that should work?

Comment: By proper security, I mean not opening sites/files to Everyone, so only HR people having access to HR information. Then if user xyz is fishing for something in the HR space, they won't find it. I think the reports are useful enough to help you hone best bets and authoritative content. Getting into the who searched for what when is going into a level or granularity that is not necessary.

Comment: I see. We are planning on some other custom reports such as # of logins per day, and most viewed article... we are planning to use the same approach of using SharePoint List. For most viewed, we were hoping to use Audit Log report, but in SharePoint online, audit for read of the items are not accessible.

We have a Most Popular Items button on the Library hosting the articles but it doesn't seem to return anything. Different experience from what is mentioned here: http://sharepoint-community.net/profiles/blogs/popularity-trends-in-your-sharepoint-online-team-site

Comment: I'd look into using Google Analytics possibly over rolling it on your own. I think you'd be able to create an app and then staple it to all your sites.